# History of drive-by exploits

Tags: drive-by-download

I am interested in drive-by download attacks. For the moment, the oldest article I found on internet treating about it is [this one](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/6645895.stm). 
Does someone know when first the expression drive-by download attack was used ?
 And what was the first successful attack ever performed ?

Comment: @RoryAslop why is my question out-off topic ? am I asking about potatoes ?

Comment: "History of information security" is, at best, marginally on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *concept* of drive-by downloads dates back at least to 1996, with the introduction of automatic downloading of [ActiveX controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) in Internet Explorer 3.  I don't remember if it was called drive-by downloading at the time, or just "a really stupid idea".

Answer (score 1):

Drive-by downloads are usually used in browser exploit-kits, as well as in malicious advertisements. I haven't found the origin of the term, but there are some articles. [This paper](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/course/cs260r/papers/spycrawler-ndss06.pdf), published in 2006, analyzes drive-by downloads from 2005.

A [Symantec article](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/drive-downloads-hook-or-crook) from 2006 explains that the WMF vulnerability was popular.

HP DVLabs reports on web exploit-kits:

> The trend started in 2006 with the release of WebAttacker, which is considered by many to be the first modern day Web exploit toolkit.

Comment: The german wikipedia has linked a source from 2004 but sadly itn't available any more. But you can read it on archive.org http://web.archive.org/web/20051110164059/http://www.windowsitlibrary.com/Content/1160/22/1.html